# Getting undefined map error....Typerror while using the map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm getting this **"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"**

```
const Categories = () => {
    return (
    <Container>
       {categories.map((item) =>(
        <CategoryItem key={item.id}/>
       ))}
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: where have you defined `categories`?

Answer (score 0):

categories is undefined so the map function is not available.

if you want to return no category items in this case you can do chained operator to test categories is not null first
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

```js
const Categories = () => {
    return (
    <Container>
       {categories?.map((item) =>(
        <CategoryItem key={item.id}/>
       ))}
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means your `categories` variable is not defined, make sure it does have a value and its a valid array.